# Create a custom windows output device

Tags: c#, windows, audio

I want to create a custom windows sound output device. If you select this device in your sound settings (Playback device) it will send the sound stream via custom code to a socket, listening on an other device. The problem ist, that I dont realy know how to do it.

I normaly program Python and Flutter / Android and dont know much about windows programming.

I read in the microsoft documentations that the MMDevice API can mabe help me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/coreaudio/mmdevice-api

Please give me some advices

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only legal way to create an audio endpoint is to implement an audio driver that emulates a hardware audio device. See MSVAD and SysVad examples in MS WDK.

Comment: Now I'm interested, what is an illegal way of accomplishing this goal?

Comment: For example, you can inject a code into any active process to intercept all audio interface (WASAPI, MME, DirectSound, AudioGraph etc.) API calls. You need to intercept both static and dynamic linking to these APIs. Such technique is typical for the malware, so you most likely will get false-positives from various malware detectors.